# Missing eddy currents in copper?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have a set of little flywheels that have a magnet to break the motion of the system. I have one aluminum and several copper ones all water jet cut roughly to size. The copper and aluminum disks I have are all the same dimensions but bought from three different sources.
Yesterday I machined the Aluminum disc and three of the copper discs to the correct specs on the lathe.

I checked the amount of drag caused by these discs some time ago and found the copper was far more effective than the aluminum. Today I needed to check the operating distance of the magnet so repeated this test on the newly machined parts and was shocked to find the three copper discs provided so little drag it bearly registered. The aluminum and the other copper ones worked very well. The drag the magnet courses on the other copper wheels is considerable so the difference is huge, one copper disc brings the whole system to a halt immediately but with the other discs I machined yesterday I can barely feel any drag at all, at first I was unsure there was any until I spun it up faster then I could just about feel some slight resistance.

I thought the strength of the eddy currents produced was dictated by the conductivity of the metal used so I am now confused as to what happened here. As I said before the copper discs are from three different sources so maybe different coppers. Does anyone know what has gone wrong and if it's the copper which coppers are best for use in this job?

Comment: Have you used your multimeter to check resistance across the disks.  That would be the first thing I would check. You have have trouble if the resistance is too low, in which case, you will have to measure current from a standard voltage.  Next, double check your geometry.  That much difference makes me think the distances are different or the disks are thinner or something.

Comment: You should include diagrams of the relevant parts of your set up (position of magnet relative to wheel/disk) and use case, The problem has to be in the metal, it's dimensions, or the relevant mechanism/positioning, so be sure to outline the mechanism that engages the magnet.  Air gap variance between magnet and disc is a possible cause, although if you used a lathe I assume you bothered to make all relevant dimensions identical..

Comment: Parts are discs, 100mm diameter by 6mm thick. All the same. No need to measure anything in the mechanism. The difference is dramatic. If you pass a magnet across the copper ones they move across the table. If you pass a magnet across the unknown ones you can bearly feel any resistance.

Comment: I'll try and mesure the resitance tomorrow,